# total count of messages received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed this guide on building a message feature with Rails https://github.com/mickyginger/rails-conversations it's not a chatroom, but a one-to-one message system.  basically it requires you to create a conversation table and then a message table.  The message table belongs_to both the User and Conversation models.

Everything is working good that was covered in the tutorial.  I wanted to add the capability to see a total message count for each user and have it displayed on the user profile page when they login.

So if 3 separate people send 1 message each to User_A then on User_A's profile page it should say "you have 3 new messages"

I wasn't sure if it would be better to create something in the users `show` action?  or to put it in the `application_controller` ?

it tried the below but every user other than the one that sent it will receive the notification (user_id is the user who sent the message).

```
# displays the number of unread messages in a conversation for the current_user
def unread_message_cnt(current_user)
  Message.where("user_id != ? AND read = ?", current_user.id, false).count
end
```

I also tried getting the conversation id and looking up the message based on that.  But now I'm looping through each conversatin and not getting a total count.

```
def unread_message_cnt(current_user)
  @conversations = Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
  @conversations.each do |convo|
    Message.where("conversation_id = ? AND read = ? AND user_id != ?", convo.id, false, current_user.id,).count
  end
end
```

also I'm open to other suggestions if there is a better messaging solution.  I would prefer **not** to use a gem though.

as requested adding model info..

conversation model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "receiver_id"

  # each conversation will have one or more messages.
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  # only one conversation is created between two users, regardless of 
  # who is the receiver and who is the sender.
  # The scope option limits the uniqueness check to just receiver_id.
  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :receiver_id

  # finds a conversation between two users, regardless of who the sender and receiver are.
  scope :between, ->(sender_id,receiver_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.receiver_id = ?) OR 
    (conversations.receiver_id = ? AND conversations.sender_id = ?)", sender_id, receiver_id, sender_id, receiver_id)
  end  

  # return the other user (ie. not the current_user) from the conversation.
  def recipient(current_user)
    self.sender_id == current_user.id ? self.receiver : self.sender
  end

  # displays the number of unread messages in a conversation
  def unread_message_count(current_user)
    self.messages.where("user_id != ? AND read = ?", current_user.id, false).count
  end  

end
```

message model

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

end
```

in the user model I added

```
 has_many :conversations, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Can you add your models to see more in detail the associations?

Comment: updated with my models.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track when you decided to go through the conversations.
Try the following:

```
conversations = Conversation.
  where("receiver = :user_id OR sender = :user_id", user_id: currenct_user.id)

Message.where(conversation: conversations).
  where.not(user: current_user).where(read: false).count
```

I further suggest that you add the `unread` scope to your messages model for readability,

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :unread, -> { where(read: false) }
  ...
end
```

Now you can write:

```
Message.where(conversation: conversations).
  where.not(user: current_user).unread.count
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to chain a `where` right after `not`?

Comment: @Francisco awesome, thanks!  I added the `where` before the `not` like @Sebastian mentioned as well.   It's working great!